# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

(OS: Windows 10; XAMPP v3.2.2; Visual Studio Code 1.20.0)

I have a problem with php mysqli. It says that the function mysqli_connect isn't definded. There are a lot of solutions I tried - even in Stack Overflow - but none of this solutions work for me.

I've upgraded PHP from 5 to 7. In my phpinfo mysqli not seems to be enabled. So I checked if there is a php_mysqli.dll file in my php-folder (I had exchanged the php folder in xampp-folder with the new php (7) folder). I found in "C:\xampp\php\ext". So the next step was to check the php.ini for "extension=php_mysqli.dll". I found and removed the ";" in front of it. I saved the document and restarted the Apache-Server. It doesn't work.

The exception thrown is:

```html
    <br /> 
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\BMult\Archive.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\BMult\Archive.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

The statement throwing the error is:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
```

Comment: make sure your new install isn't picking anything up from the previous installation. That is usually the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check this evening (MEZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to install a newer XAMPP version. I removed XAMPP and installed a newer version and now it works.

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html